# How are compound nodes represented in Cytoscape JSON output?

Tags: json, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm trying to export a network from cytoscape.js in JSON format for use with Cytoscape.  My networks consist of nodes and compound nodes.  The export mechanism is simply `JSON.stringify(cy)`.  The exported JSON file from cytoscape.js can be imported in Cytoscape 3.7.2, but I lose all compound node parent-child relationships.  The compound nodes just float as singletons.

To generate a "proper" JSON file from Cytoscape, I tried creating three nodes (no edges); group two of the nodes (they collapse and expand together when double-clicked); and export the network in JSON format.  The output file contains references to three nodes and one group, but when reimported, the grouping relationship is gone (double-clicking on the grouped nodes or the group does nothing).

Can someone please explain how to generate a JSON file that contains compound nodes that can be imported properly in Cytoscape?  Thanks.